# Oracle - to_date() parse of 00:00:00

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle12c, toad

I am trying to format into Date from Date string by following the way,

```
select to_date('11/19/2019 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as currentdate from dual;
```

The output should be,

```
11/19/2019 12:00:00 AM
```

But, I am getting the output as,

```
11/19/2019
```

[image]

When I execute following,

```
select to_date('11/19/2019 00:00:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as currentdate from dual;
```

The correct output I am getting,

```
11/19/2019 12:00:01 AM
```

[image]

My `nls_date_format` is `DD-MON-RR`.

[image]

My `nls_time_format` is `HH.MI.SSXFF AM`.

[image]

I want output in the mentioned format. For all other values except than `00:00:00` is working fine.

Why `00:00:00` is not converting into the required format? Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: In your question you say: "I am trying to convert Date object" `select to_date('11/19/2019 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as currentdate from dual;` That query will never get you this result: `11/19/2019 12:00:00 AM`. Please correct this first select so we actualy see what you are converting from. Thanks!

Comment: To explain little bit more, in your select the time is 00:00:00 and you want to get 12:00:00 from that without any additional operations ?

Comment: Please send us your nls_date_format ? Thanks! This is how you will read it: `select *
from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';`

Comment: @VBokšić my nls_date_format `DD-MON-RR`.

Comment: You are telling us some wrong info then. You can not get this: `11/19/2019 12:00:01 AM` from this `select to_date('11/19/2019 00:00:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as currentdate from dual;` when your nls_date_format is this `DD-MON-RR`. Here is the DEMO: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b84b2daf3fcbba0c7aec67a2e26b57b7

Comment: @VBokšić I have run the query you have given. It is giving me this `DD-MON-RR` output.

Comment: The query from my answer ?

Comment: @VBokšić from your comment.

Comment: Please read my other comments. Thanks

Comment: @VBokšić I have updated the question already.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare What is the User Interface you are using to access the database? SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, Toad, Java, Python, something else?

Comment: @MTO Screenshot is from Toad. But even I am running using the Java then also the same issue.

Comment: I still do not understand how you can get a result with 'AM' inside with this query and  this nls_date_format. Sorry but something is not adding up. When we talk about PM and AM then you do not have time 00:00:00. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock

Comment: @VBokšić I don't know. But as I mentioned above I am getting the output.

Comment: Can you check your NLS_TIME_FORMAT ? Thanks!

Comment: @VBokšić `NLS_TIME_FORMAT` is `HH.MI.SSXFF AM`.

Comment: Check my answer , I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the AM format you will need this:

```
select to_char(to_date('19/11/2019 12:00:00 AM','dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') 
from dual;
```

If you run it like this:

```
select to_char(to_date('19/11/2019 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') 
from dual;
```

You will get an error.
When your date format is not 24 hours(hh24) then your value for hour needs to be between 1 and 12.

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4cf6cf45887ed2016408a3158be43d95)

After some research I have realised what OP wants(from his comments and after he entered some more details).
Solution for OP is:

Step 1:

```
ALTER session SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM';
```

Step 2 now this will work:

```
select to_date('11/19/2019 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as currentdate from dual;
```

Answer (score 4):

You *are* getting the correct output. Only it is *displayed* in the default date format of your session (or database), which seems to be `mm/dd/yyyy`.

You control the default date format of your session with paramter `nls_date_format`:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
select to_date('11/19/2019 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as currentdate from dual;
```

Alternatively, you can use `to_char()` to format your date to a specific format:

```
select to_char(
    to_date('11/19/2019 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
    'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
) as currentdate from dual;
```

Comment: But, If i ran `00:00:01` then it is showing proper output `11/19/2019 12:00:01 AM`.